# Nuclear launch alert

Tags: security, iphone-app

Is there an app or feature in iOS that can notify its owner of an impending missile, nuclear or otherwise, headed towards a particular location (or a nuclear launch of any sort)? All I seem to be able to find on the App Store are games. I'm asking for a friend.

In case it helps, the locale in question is Canada, near the US border.

Comment: [Red Alert](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/red-alert-israel/id873642097?mt=8) will do this for Israel. I am unaware of - and I doubt there is - any global solution. There are [RSOE's Alert Map](http://hisz.rsoe.hu/alertmap/index2.php) and [Google Crisis Map](https://www.google.org/crisismap) but they don't monitor missiles.

Answer (score -2):

If you were a member of your countries security forces there is probably one that you can get but as a private individual I very much doubt it.

But when you think about it how far can you run with ten minutes warning, or even half an hour.

Rephrasing: There probably is but it if so it will be restricted to security services, etc.

Comment: I, er, my friend isn't worried about a direct strike. More of a "duck and cover" scenario.

Comment: More of a comment than answer, No?